# Border width of 1 physical pixel

Tags: css, mobile-website

Have a task, to make block's border width of 1 physical pixel in spite of device pixelratio.

Project uses

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

And because of this, `border: 1px solid black;` on different devices have different border width depending of pixelratio. I need avoid it, and make border width of 1 physical pixel.

Comment: Have you set the viewport width? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: There is no such css value as `physical pixel`..

Comment: @SamWillis yes, written it in question

Comment: @Paulie_D i know, but i wondering is there any way to make such behaviour

Comment: Not really...you'd have to use javascript I suspect and even then I have no idea how it would render.. and whether or not it would even be visible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approximate this in pure CSS is to use media queries based on the resolution.

```css
div {
  margin:.5em 0;
  border:1px solid red;
}
@media (min-resolution: 2dppx) {
  div.devicedot {border-width:.5px;}
}
@media (min-resolution: 3dppx) {
  div.devicedot {border-width:.34px;}
}
@media (min-resolution: 4dppx) {
  div.devicedot {border-width:.25px;}
}
@media (min-resolution: 6dppx) {
  div.devicedot {border-width:.17px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="normal">This is normal</div>
<div class="devicedot">This is with a device dot</div>
```

Of course the actual queries depend on your needs: if you want to print this on a 1200dpi printer, you will have to include a query for 12dppx. (If you really can use a 0.02 mm wide line, that is.)

And please note that this example is simplified, assuming browsers that have full `@media` support. If you use this on an actual website that can be visited by anyone, include safeguards like `@media all and ...`